# UIKIt.UIImage does not contain a defintion for Save and no extension method save of type UIKit.UIImage not found.Are you mIssing assembly reference?

Tags: c#, ios, image, xamarin.ios

I am trying to convert an image to Base64 string in monotouch iOS app. I used below coding to do it. but error occurred.

```
 using (Image image = Image.FromFile(Path))
{                 
    using (MemoryStream m = new MemoryStream())
    {
        image.Save(m, image.RawFormat);
        byte[] imageBytes = m.ToArray();

        // Convert byte[] to Base64 String
        string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(imageBytes);
        return base64String;
    }
```

now probelm is, Save does not have any definition. And RawFormat does not have definiton and no extension method. what can i do now?

Comment: Your title says `UIImage` but your code is using `Image`. The later is not a type from Xamarin.iOS. Are you using something else ? like Xamarin.Forms or System.Drawing ?

Comment: i am working in cross platform mobile app using c#. so there is UIImage @poupou

Comment: The _usual_ UIKit (and `UIImage`) are *not* cross-platform, *only* iOS has them (if you're using something unconventional for your cross-platform project please tell us what it is). Also your code above does *not* use `UIImage` but `Image`.

Answer (score 0):

if the image already exists on disk, it is simpler to do

```
byte[] data = File.ReadAllBytes(path);

// Convert byte[] to Base64 String
string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(imageBytes);
return base64String;
```

Comment: i did this method. but  base64 string size is above 10 lakhs. so php reply uri is too large. so what can  i do now mr.jason

Comment: How to attach this base64string to php url?

Comment: If the string is too big for your server, you can reduce the size of the image, or break it up into multiple pieces, or change the server to allow bigger requests, or any number of things.